# AppleScript variant of find(1)

Tags: applescript

How would I write the following as an AppleScript command without the use of bash scripting?

```
find / -file foo.txt
```

I might have the bash syntax wrong, but I want to search from the root of the drive for a specific filename.

I tried drawing multiple efforts from things around on the net, but I just need a simple "find" solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finder has an `entire contents` command for listing all items in a directory tree:

```
tell application "Finder"
    files of entire contents of (POSIX file "/usr/share/doc" as alias) where name is "bashref.html"
end tell
```

It will be really slow if you search in the root of the volume though. If you need to search for all files on the volume, you can use mdfind or locate:

```
do shell script "mdfind -name bashref.html -onlyin /"
```

```
do shell script "locate bashref.html"
```

Comment: Even though the answer by patrix does what I wanted in perfect simplicity, I was after a totally AppleScript based solution. Your solution does precisely what I need.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You definitively have the `find` syntax wrong here :-)

To search for a file across the builtin disk use

```
find -x / -name filename.ext -print
```

If you want to search across all disks (including USB drives etc) use

```
find / -name filename.ext -print
```

Comment: I built upon your answer to use: `find /path/to/dir -name FileName.txt`

This does exactly what I needed. Eg - `find /Applications -name '1Password.app'`

Answer (score 1):

you could use find from inside the applescript

`set result to (do shell script "find -name / filename.ext"`